# Как вырезать 2 куска строки (вылетает OutOfMemory Exception)

Tags: java, строки

Доброго времени суток. У меня имеется метод , который на выходе имеет 2 поля:

1. С какой позиции заканчивается индекс, который нужен для объекта Spannable (чтобы делать текст жирным, наклонным или подчеркнутым)
2. С какой позиции надо вырезать html тег из строки.
   Каждый раз этот самый метод находит такую позицию, что при взятии подстроки, внутри оказывается одинаковое количество открытых и закрытых тегов.
   В другом методе я обрабатываю эти индексы не очень грамотно (раз вылетают ошибки OutOfMemory)

   ```
   str = str.substring(0, start) + str.substring(openTagEnd, closeTagStart) + str.substring(closeTagEnd);
   ```

Подскажите наиболее адекватный и экономный (в плане памяти) способ срезать 2 подстроки.
p.s. теги часто повторяются

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело скорее всего не в обработке индексов. Хотя здесь можно слегка сэкономить, но это не решит проблемы.

Либо вы работаете с довольно большим объемом данных, и тогда вам нужно использовать внешнюю память (например диск), или, если данных не так много, просто выделить JVM больше памяти при запуске.

Возможно вы порождаете утечки памяти, и тогда нужно смотреть на другой код.

Утечки довольно легко породить с использованием метода `substring`. Сценарий такой:

1. Создаем исходную большую строку (например 1024 символа)
2. Вызываем метод `substring` и ссылку на полученную в результате вызова строку (длинной например 20 символов) где-то сохраняем.
3. Исходная строка нам больша не нужна и собрана GC, но в строке, созданной с помощью `substring` используется тот же самый исходный массив символов из большой строки.

В итоге вы думаете, что у вас осталась только строка длинной 20 символов, но по факту все 1024 символа все еще занимают память. См. реализацию метода `substring`.

Возможно у вас где-то живут ссылки на исходные большие строки.

Возможно вам не нужно хранить результат ваших вычислений в памяти и можно его сразу сбрасывать на диск.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использовать [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). `StringBuilder` идеально подходит в случае множественных манипуляция со строками. В частности `StringBuilder.append()` вместо `String str=str1+str2` ну и аналогично со всеми `substring` и проч.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(str);
StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
str = sb2.append(sb.substring(0, start)).append(sb.substring(openTagEnd, 
  closeTagStart)).append(sb.substring(closeTagEnd)).toString();
```

Comment: использование StringBuilder оправданно, если конкатениция строк происходит в цикле.

Comment: Ваш код и код автора вопроса с точки зрения компилятора практически одно и тоже. За тем исключением, что вы используете больше памяти (буфер в `StringBuilder` плюс сама строка).

Конкатенация строк через `+` транслируется компилятором в создание экземпляра `StringBuilder` (на каждую отдельную строку кода с конкатенацией).

Comment: @a_gura повторюсь, если конкатениция не в цикле.

Comment: @Andreich Это следует из того, что я сказал, т.к. в цикле на каждую итерацию будет создан новый экземпляр `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @a_gura да, да, все верно. забылся.

Comment: @a_gura в гробу я видел оптимизаторов полагающихся на компилятор: во первых компиляторы бывают разные, во вторых оптимизация компилятора управляется ключами компилятора, в третьих указанная вами подстановка стала работать относительно недавно, ну и в конце-концов таки я сторонник оптимизации **кода**. Ну и к тому же ни я ни вы не знаете в цикле работает у ТС этот код или нет.

Comment: @Barmaley Во-первых, да, бывают, но как еще можно сложить строки (разве что сделать свой велосипед типа StringBuilder). Во-вторых, это не оптимизация. В-третьих, относительно недавно, это с Java 1.4 :) Про цикл все абсолютно очевидно в рамках данной конкретной строки кода.